# How do I print certain outputs within awk command

Tags: awk

**file1**

```
area@wide.com
geo@earth.com
sun@far.com
```

**file2**

```
area@wide.com:200
moon@mars.com:100
venus@distance.com:0
geo@earth.com:201
sun@far.com:10
```

**file3** should look like:

```
area@wide.com:200
geo@earth.com:201
sun@far.com:10
```

I tried:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}'
```

Comment: Why are you using commas as a delimiter, when there don't seem to be any commas in the data?

Comment: again I was testing it out but it should be ":"

Comment: Can you paste your actual command, and the output?  The question doesn't make much sense as-is.  Are you trying to only show lines from file2, where the first field appears in file1?

Comment: I've edited the file structures and what the output should look like

Comment: @awkselfish, IMHO you should really post correct samples(which are near to your actual Input_file(s)), codes posted in 2 posts were working for your samples but then Sundeep used his nice trick to remove spaces from your lines and it got it worked, so please always work on your samples to give us clear picture about your question, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} $1 in a' file1 file2
```

- `-F:` set `:` as field separator
- `NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}` build array keys based on complete line contents of `file1`
- `$1 in a` print line from `file2` if first field is a key in array `a`

Looks like your files may have dos-style line ending, in which case you can use:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{sub(/\r$/, ""); a[$0]; next} $1 in a' file1 file2
```

Here, the carriage return at the end of lines in `file1` is removed before using it as a key, thus it will match first field of `file2`. Also, output will be dos-style.

See also [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

If there are whitespace characters like space, tab, etc at end of line, that can also cause issue. In such a case, use

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{sub(/[[:space:]]*$/, ""); a[$0]; next} $1 in a' file1 file2
```

This will remove extra whitespaces at end of line before using it as a key. This will also work for dos-style files.

Comment: awk 'NR==FNR{sub(/\r$/, ""); a[$0]; next} $1 in a' file1 FS=: file2 THIS WORKED. Thank you.

Comment: does it work if you use `awk 'NR==FNR{sub(/[[:space:]]*$/, ""); a[$0]; next} $1 in a' file1 FS=: file2`

Comment: You could use `awk -F':' '...' file1 file2` instead of setting FS among the file name args after the text of the script.

Comment: @EdMorton right! I do not recall why I set it after file1, I probably started with some assumption but unable to recall now.. probably something like what if file1 has `:` character but then `$1` for file2 cannot have `:` character